# How to remove PyCharm from Windows right-click context menu?

Tags: windows, pycharm

When I right click with my mouse then a choice of PyCharm IDE appears that reads:

> Open Folder as PyCharm Community Edition Project

How can I remove the choice?

[image: Remove PyCharm]

Answer (score 1):

1. Open windows run with `windows + R`.
2. Enter `regedit`
3. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\PyCharm Community Edition`
4. Delete the folder `PyCharm Community Edition`

Repeat from step 3 with `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with PyCharm Community Edition` and `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PyCharm Community Edition`